# C++ Partially-Filled Arrays, Deleting Odds Values

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function removeOdds() that removes all of the odd numbers in its array parameter. The function returns the number of items removed, or -1 if the array is initially empty. The function takes 2 arguments:

• the array of int that will be modified

• the size of the array (use size_t as the type)

I do not know how to delete the duplicated evens?

```
int removeOdds(int a[], size_t size){
    int count = 0;
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    if(!(n > 0)){
        return -1;
        }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(a[i]%2 == 1){
            a[i] = a[i+1];
            count++;
            }
        }
        size = count;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);` will not give you the size because array parameters are [depleted to pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829830/c-passing-an-array-pointer-as-a-function-argument). It will be always `sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 2):

```
static bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }  /* Predicate function */

int removeOdds(int a[], size_t size)
{
  if(0 == size) return -1;  /* -1 if the array is initially empty */
  /* Shift all the odd elements to the end */
  int *new_end = std::remove_if (&a[0], &a[size], IsOdd); // #include <algorithm>
  /* number of items removed */
  return static_cast<int>(new_end - &a[0]);
}
```

In `C++11`, you can use more fancy lambda functions instead of IsOdd.