# cannot pass float array out of a function

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point

I'm new to c++, and I want to pass a float array out of a function using a pointer. However, the returning array is always 0; I am running on an Arduino Uno.

This is my code. I want the readSensor() function to pass out a float array consisting of 3 floats. The float array should be pass to the pointer output*. But when I print out readings, it shows 0.00 instead of the values I passed out.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  float readings[3];
  readSensor(readings);
  for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
    Serial.println(readings[i]);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

// pass out these 3 floats
float val1 = 3.14159;
float val2 = 2.741;
float val3 = 87;
void readSensor(float* output) {
  float container[3] = {val1, val2, val3};
  output = container;
}
```

Comment: What does ` output ` point to? An editable array of at least 3 elements?

Comment: Why do you use raw pointer in C++? Is this part of the interface?

Comment: what I hope to do is to pass the container array to the "output" arrray, which is the "readings" in my case. I'm really new maybe this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Steven97102 You are using the wrong construct.  Just use `std::array`, not dumb arrays, and then most of your code would remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "pass an array out of a function" in the way you seek.   C++ offers no such mechanism by simply using a pointer and a raw (C-style) array.

In your particular approach

> ```
> void readSensor(float* output) {
>  float container[3] = {val1, val2, val3};
>  output = container;
> }
> ```

`container` ceases to exist when the function returns.  Also, `output` is passed by value, so the assignment `output = container` is not visible to the caller.

It is necessary to pass a pointer to (the first element of) an array into the function, and have the function copy data to it as needed.  For example,

```
void readSensor(float* output)
{
     float container[3] = {1, 2, 3};
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        output[i] = container[i];
}
```

And the caller must supply the array and pass it.

```
int main()
{
     float result[3];
     readSensor(result);   // data will be copied into result
     // use result here
}
```

Bear in mind that the caller is responsible for calling the function correctly.  For example if the caller of the function above passes an array with two elements, the behaviour is undefined.

A preferred way in C++ is to use a standard container, such as a `std::vector`.  For example;

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> readSensor()
{
     float container[3] = {1, 2, 3};
     std::vector<float> output;
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        output.push_back(container[i]);
     return output;
}

int main()
{
     std::vector<float> result;
     result = readSensor();
     // use result here
}
```

If you don't know how to use standard containers, there is plenty of documentation around.

Comment: You can just `return {1,2,3};`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - yes, that is true.  However, this question is obviously asked by a beginner.   And that syntax will look like it is returning an array, even though it is doing something quite different (constructing a vector using an initialiser list and returning that).

Answer (score 2):

```
void readSensor(float* output) 
{
    float container[3] = {val1, val2, val3};
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        output[i] = container[i];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it would be helpful to explain why.

Comment: Technically correct, but it's important to explain that this is a bad way of returning an array.

Comment: Can you explain what's a better approach?

Comment: @Steven97102 Use `std::array` and never look back.

Comment: @Steven97102 I think [this link's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829830/c-passing-an-array-pointer-as-a-function-argument) description will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
void readSensor(float* output) {
  float container[3] = {val1, val2, val3};
  output = container;
}
```

Here you are creating an array `container` on the stack and initializing it, and assigning the address of its first element to `output`. You then destroy `container` when you reach the end of the function, and by the time the function returns, the array that `output` used to point to no longer exists.

j.doe's answer is one solution to this, but you have to be careful to ensure `output` already points to an array of sufficient size *before* assigning values to it. You could also consider looking into [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Not only does the array that `output` used to point to no longer exist, but `output` also no longer exists. Assigning a value to a non-reference parameter does not change anything in the calling code.

Comment: @JaMiT You're right, I missed the way in which the OP was calling the function. Good catch